# Multiple websites using same Yii Folder

Tags: php, yii

I have a small problem. I have several websites that need to be put on different servers.

All of these websites are using the Yii framework. I want to host the Yii framework on a seperate server and have all the websites refer to this server.

I tried adding the url in the index.php but i keep getting this error :

```
require_once(): Failed opening required

ftp:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0
```

Comment: Why you can't just have Yii in each server? Requesting Yii via FTP only slows down your website.

Comment: The folder is 24,8 MB and that is too big apparently. So i was instructed to try and host it elsewhere.

Comment: 24.8MB too big? A few images later and you will be in the same position.

Comment: even if this is possible, I dont recommend you to do it !

Comment: Is there a reason besides slowing down my website ? My boss just wants to save space.

Comment: this becomes a single point of failure for all sites. besides that it stops you from upgrading yii on any site without touching the other sites. Not on last it is SLOW. The space you are going to save is very small(approx. 24Mb) compared to the mess that might happen.

Comment: Change your host provider

Answer (score 0):

If you have shell access permission of your servers. You can host Yii in one server, share the Yii folder. In another servers you can mount shared folder and use it like a local folder..